# ZXing QR Code/Barcode scanning

Tags: android, zxing

I had tried to integrate QRCode scanner to my application by firing an intent 
The code I used is the follwing

```
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

//The Response collection

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // Handle successful scan
    String capturedQrValue =
    intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    Log.i("info", "captureQrValue :" + capturedQrValue);
    String format =
    intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
    Toast.makeText(
    One.this,
    "Scan Result:" + capturedQrValue + " scan format :"+ format,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // Handle cancel
    }
    } else {
    }
```

Even though I am facing a problem that it is not working if the ZXing sample barcode scanner is not installed.

EDIT:

- Is it possible to make Barcode Scanner as a part of my app. Am not interested in downloading Barcode Scanner.
- Also is there  any camera or android version specification for ZXing QRCode scanning???

Not working means - it's asking to install Barcode Scanner from google play which I need to avoid.

Comment: On SO, when you say "not working" you really should specify what.

Comment: Query updated with enough explanation I hope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer/advise to use Zbar instead of zxing. zxing takes time to read qr code when compared to zbar and also u may need to install their own(zxing) app - [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) for scanning. I have tried both and I found zbar better. Download zbar source code from [here](https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner). Unzip the file and import the ZBarScannerLibrary as a library project. Add this library to your android application. Also add this to your scanButton `

```
if (check_if_camera_is_available) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MyWallet.this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
} 
else 
{

    Toast.makeText(MyWallet.this, "Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}`
```

Also declare these variables in your activity otherwise you may hit error

```
private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;
private static final int ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 1;
```

Finally in your manifest file add this

```
<activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This project will no longer be maintained. [This](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) would be a better suggest

Answer (score 2):

Zxing is open source and you can include it in your app *(but the creator of this lib discourages this behavior reading in stackoveflow questions)*.

Although you must respect the Apache license 2.0 of ZXing.

Is quite simple:

1. include the lib in your project
2. correct some code for a [problem in android while generating `R`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226941/error-in-switch-cases-of-zxing-project-in-android)
3. the `application` in zxing manifest must be like this `<application/>`
4. start an intent or create your own `public class ScanActivity extends CaptureActivity` and manage the results

   ```
   @Override
   public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor){
       String barcodeRead = rawResult.getText();

       if(!MyValidator.isMyBarcode(barcodeRead))return;

       Intent viewDetails = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
       viewDetails.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_BARCODE, barcodeRead);
       viewDetails.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_SESSION, "some extras");
       startActivity(viewDetails);

       finish();
   }
   ```

**The last but not the least add some credit to this lib in your app!!**

Comment: To be clear: I *encourage* people to reuse any of the open source code. But it must be done in a way that respects the law. This includes respecting trademark and copyright. The problem comes when people copy and paste the whole app. Just don't do that.